# How to apply custom logics on spark dataframe using scala

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset, scala-spark

Imagine a data for this question is in a nested json structure. I have flattened the data from json using **explode()** and added it into one data-frame with columns **project**, **Task**, **Task-Evidence**, **Task-Remarks**, **Project-Evidence**

*Note: This DF is having 1 Project for which it has 2 Tasks, for the first task it has 1 task-link, for the second task it has 1 task-link. at project level we have 3  project-links.

[**Result of DF**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oYh6.png)

[**Expected Result**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Es33R.png)

Comment: your expected df isn't a valid table. The JSON which you already have is perfect for what you want to achieve, You can create a dataframe with JSON column  where each rows is one project and use in your code, instead of exploding and trying to create the "JSONish" structure again

Answer (score 0):

AFAIU, If you flattened the json, then you just need to group tasks, task-evidence, ... by Project, so you can group by project and use `collect_set`, something thing like this:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df2 = df.groupBy("project").agg(
            collect_set("Task").as("Tasks"),
            collect_set("Task-Evidence").as("Task-Evidences"),
            collect_set("Task-Remarks").as("Task-Remarks"),
            collect_set("Project-Evidence").as("Project-Evidences")
        )
```

Comment: But this just groups multiple elements in columns into an list

Comment: This is what i understand from your expected results, please le me know if this is not the case